# Confused with symfony2 bundles

Tags: php, plugins, symfony

I am little bit confused with symfony2 bundles.

I want to know that does everything in symfony is bundle including main application.

I was thinking as Core of site is somewhere i can write code to use bundles like we use plugins from main application code.

Or there is no core thing in Symfony . The core itself will be bundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony2 is bundle-based framework
=> So, everything, as well as the core itself is a bundle.

You can see which bundle is loaded by default in app/AppKernel.php.

But Symfony2 does also include a library, organized by "components (vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Components). Code in bundle can use this library..

Answer (score 5):

you can define your website completely as a bundle, meaning

```
Mycompany/MywebsiteBundle
```

Or you can define the different, sections of your website as different bundle, which i personally preffer

```
`Mycompany/ForumBundle
 Mycompany/BlogBundle
 Mycompany/NewsletterBundle`
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, everything is a bundle. As per Symfony2 docs:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/page_creation.html#page-creation-bundles