# how to best structure application in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, bundles

I started using Symfony 2 after having experience with 5 php frameworks like Zend, CodeIgniter, Fuel, Yii and Cake. I am very confused on how to structure my project as better as I can. First of all I am confused in working with bundles. Bundles are some kind of modules used in other frameworks? Bascially I have my application and everything until now is stored in a bundles. If I want to make some helper functions and some libraries and abstract classes, I just make a new bundle for those?

Answer (score 2):

See the [*Bundle Structure and Best Practices*](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html) cookbook entry for basic ideas on the structure of a bundle.

I recommend having just one *app specific* bundle. I call it `AppBundle`.

Also, you don't have to have everything in bundles. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999433/should-everything-really-be-a-bundle-on-symfony-2) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of other discussions on that matter:

- [Should everything really be a bundle on Symfony 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999433/should-everything-really-be-a-bundle-on-symfony-2)
- [Confused with symfony2 bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804831/confused-with-symfony2-bundles)